# NTP Server in Network Switch

Tags: networking, hp, switch, ntp, time-synchronization

Is it possible to set up a Switch to acts an NTP Server for the devices connected to its VLAN ?
If so ,how can I implement it my HP Switch A3600 JG299A.
I want to do this because I do not have external NTP Time Source for proper time synchronization.

Comment: What does the documentation for this switch say ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this switch can act as an `NTP` server.

There are different ways to set it up, namely client/server, symmetric peers, multicast and broadcast modes. Most often you will likely set it up in a client/server mode. For this to work you  need to set up `NTP` synchronization on the switch itself and then it can act as a server for other devices on your `LAN`.

For more information look for `3600 v2 Switch Series Network Management and Monitoring Configuration Guide` on HP website. This document has a section explaining `NTP` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After setting up your switch to some source and filtering traffic by VLAN which is why I'm assuming that your servers don't have external access. Then just set your DC (If you are running a Windows domain controller) which if needed you can check out this article to set it up quickly: http://www.1337admin.org/windows-server/windows-server-2012-r2/set-domain-controller-to-use-external-ntp-time-source/ and when using the flag /manualpeerlist set it to the IP of the switch that it can access on it's VLAN.